# How to change the requestTimeout options for sqltools vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using the `vscode` extension `SQLTools`. When running complex queries that will take more than 15 seconds. When this happens the query will timeout. I checked the doc https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools on how to extend this so that I can run bigger queries but nothing was on how to increase the `queryTimeout` window. Has anyone figured out how to get around this issue or resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Change mssqlOptions.requestTimeout helped me:

```
"sqltools.connections": [
    {
      "mssqlOptions": {
        "appName": "SQLTools",
        "useUTC": true,
        "encrypt": true,
        "requestTimeout": 0
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/794)